# How to color the excel sheets using get_range method for a particular row and for particular range of columns

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to color an exsisting excel file using below c# code... I was able to color a range of column cells but I need to color it for a particular row for that column range. How can this be achieved ?

For eg: I need to color 2nd row for the column range ("AW:AW", "AY:AY")

```
excelWorkSheet5.get_Range("AW:AW", "AY:AY").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried adding the row index

```
excelWorkSheet5.get_Range("AW2", "AY2").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

Comment: No I will try and let you know